# Windows 8 not loading after Ubuntu 13.10 installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub, ubuntu-13.10

My system was running on Window 8 Pro. One thing to note is that, my system is an assembled PC. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my system. After the installation, first I was not able to boot both Ubuntu and Windows. Then after doing some commands like "sudo" in the terminal and I performed an update to the grub. I became able to boot Ubuntu properly from the grub menu. But I can't boot Windows. The grub menu shows 2 loaders for Windows. Both are not working. When selected on any of the Windows loader, it shows the Windows loading screen for some time and then suddenly a screen shows, not even for 1 second. Then the system restarts and shows the grub menu. How can I make my Windows boot ?

As I was said, I performed the following commands in the terminal :

```
sudo grub-update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Still the same problem is there. My Windows 8 is not getting loaded. When I select Windows loader from the grub menu, Windows starts to load for sometime and a screen appears showing a message "Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We are just collecting some more info and then we will restart for you". Can I solve this ? Someone please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cmd:

```
sudo grub-update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

For info on boot-repair go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Use the recommended repairs settings.